# Is this request encrypted with SSL?

Tags: jquery, perl, ssl, encryption

I am viewing a page secured by SSL on my server, (the padlock is showing in firefox) using jQuery I execute the following:

```
$.post("/cgi-bin/foobar.pl", {
    foo: "bar"
}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

I would just like to double check that this request is encrypted via. SSL?

Comment: Yes, if you provide a url that is relative to your current domain, it will take whatever domain protocol and port that is already being used. In this case, your post url will be converted to `https://yourdomain.com/cgi-bin/foobar.pl` if your current domain is `https://yourdomain.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ('https:' == document.location.protocol) {
  $.post("/cgi-bin/foobar.pl", {
      foo: "bar"
  }, function(data) {
      alert(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have setup my virtual host to force a https connection, is this additional check necessary? I guess it wouldn't hurt to include it though.

Comment: @user1796225 it makes sure that ajax call uses https. You can also use absolute url, ie. `$.post("https://server/cgi-bin/foobar.pl"..`

Comment: Sorry, I have just read my question again, I realise it may of sounded like I was asking for some code to double check. I just wanted to know if it would be encrypted if the current page is encrypted. Your reply has already answered that though, thanks. :-)

Comment: Thanks again, I think I will use the code suggested, better to be safe than sorry. I'd rather not use an absolute URL, if my virtual host name ever needs to be changed I don't want to break anything.